# What's the use of Cmd - W?

Tags: macos

[Accoring to the support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236), `Cmd - W` is used to close the front window. `Cmd - Q` is to close the app. **What is the difference and in which scenario would I want to use `Cmd - W`?** It basically closes the app, but doesn't really close it (it stays in the bar and is displayed active). It's not a function to minimize the app like in windows, it seems to to kill the open window and put the rest to a (useless, imho) sleep, instead of just killing it as a whole.

**EDIT:** Ok, the excepted behaviour isn't that one would close the app by using `Cmd - W`. Let's ask more specific: If I close the last tab of google chrome by pressing `Cmd -W`, why doesn't the browser decide to "shutdown"? What use is a browser running without a window, and when you open a new window, you only get to the start-page?

Comment: It doesn’t *kill* anything and it most certainly doesn’t put anything to sleep. It just closes a window. Like the X button in a window’s titlebar does. Why would that be useless? It appears you’re more confused about the fact that programs often keep running even with no windows open on macOS.

Comment: @DanielB The X-Button in the windows titlebar usually closes the application. At least, a user mostly expects this behaviour. There are more and more apps that work otherwise. What is the use of an application that is managed by a GUI, when all windows are closed?

Comment: Example: A calculator. Who would want to have the app still as a running process, when there is no window showing it?

Comment: “The X-Button in the windows titlebar usually closes the application.” No, it really doesn’t. It does *the exact same thing* Cmd-W does. You’re expecting Windows behavior. But you aren’t using Windows.

Comment: Even on Windows it's not true, though more common. Easy examples where it might be useful are applications that still might notify you of some kind of event (arrived mail, new social network messages).

Comment: I guess you used Calculator as an example, but if you try closing the Calculator window you will notice that the Calculator.app does indeed quit when the window is closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The concept that you are missing is that on Mac OS closing a window does not lead by default to closing the app as well. For example, I might open two projects in Xcode at the same time, and once I am done with one of them I can close its window, but the app itself would still be running.

So, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> closes active **w**indow, and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> **q**uits the app.